# Send messages using Command Prompt knowing IP address in LAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan

My laptop is connected to College LAN and It has windows 7 Ultimate. I want to send message to  my friend using IP address (using command prompt) without any external application.

How can I send message to a computer knowing it's IP address using command prompt in LAN ?

**Update :**
I searched on Google and [found](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-159745-send-message-through-command-prompt-with-ip) this and lots of more stuff, tried but none of them working on Windows 7.

If you know any freeware or third party software that can make this possible please suggest me but I can install that on my computer only.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=send+message+using+cmd&l

Comment: @kirill2485 I tried it before I posted the question here. It is not working I am using Windows 7.

Comment: What’s keeping you from using third-party software?

Comment: @DanielB I can install any third party software to my laptop but not others (don't want to tell other to install). Please suggest some.

Comment: Well, it’s all about compromise, right? ;) It won’t work without third-party software. Unfortunately, most forms of self-organizing (broadcast/multicast) chat software might be forbidden in your network’s ToS.